# Play: Is it possible to extract form data without binding it to a model?

Tags: java, playframework

At the moment I'm trying to extract information of individual form fields from form POST requests, & I thought it would be something like this. Here's an exmaple:

In HTML

```
<form action="..." method="POST">
    <input name="field-name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And to get the information from the Controller:

```
String field = Form.form.get('field-name');
```

I've been searching the docs, and all the examples I've found have been binding a request to a model class, which generates a model. I don't want to this in a few cases, as I want to pull the indivisual fields and manipulate the data.

edit: corrected some late night spelling errors

Comment: this .NET style is not possible with java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`DynamicForm`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/data/DynamicForm.html) to get fields by name in a controller.

```
DynamicForm form = form().bindFromRequest();
String fieldValue = form.get("field-name");
```

or even shorter:

```
String name = form().bindFromRequest().get("field-name");
```